# javascript sends data to php by XMLHttpRequest,also want the php send some data back

Tags: php, javascript, sql, json, xmlhttprequest

I create a xhr in js to send some data to a php file. The php file will insert these data into database. Now I need to know the auto increased ID. I use

```
echo mysql_insert_id();
```

to get the ID in php.
How can I read this value in javascript?

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

 xhr.open(
         "POST",
         "xxx.php",true
     );
    var postContainer = new Array();
    postContainer.push(
    {
        data1 : value1, 
        data2 : value2,
    });
    var newJ = JSON.stringify(postContainer); 
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json");
    xhr.send(newJ);
```

Comment: You should consider using a javascript framework for xhr. It makes things **A LOT** easier. Take a look at [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). Here is how you make an [ajax request](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) in jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach an event handler to listen for the `onreadystatechange` event.

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
   // check to make sure response finished and status is 200 meaning OK 
   if ( xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200 ){
        console.log( xhr.responseText );        
   }
}
```

Comment: In the third line the xmlhttp should be xml. Thank you !